# Angular 2 Data-Binding and setTimeout

Tags: angular

It seems that changing a component's attribute inside a 'setTimeout' function doesn't work on the initial page load.

Let's say I have a component 'HomeComponent' with attribute:

```
isValueTrue: boolean = false;
```

If I apply this attribute to an HTML element using data-binding:

```
<div [class.myClass]="isValueTrue"></div>
```

and set the value in my ngOnInit() class like:

```
this.isValueTrue = true;
```

It works!

However, if I apply it this way:

```
let comp = this;
setTimeout(() => comp.isValueTrue = true, 1000);
```

It won't get set on the initial page load. It will however work on subsequent page visits, but not after a hard refresh.

I have no idea why this doesn't work, but I'm hoping it's something that was fixed in the most recent build. My project is currently using RC 5, so I'm upgrading to 2.0.0 (2016-09-14) at the moment.

Any ideas why this happens? Is it fixed in recent builds?

Answer (score 2):

It is working. I cant clearly say if there was an error in RC5..

Take a look at this plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/KOmn62IJJyr2jzt6hYh1?p=preview

```js
import {Component, NgModule} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2 [class.red]="useRed">Hello {{name}}</h2>
    </div>
  `,
  styles: [
    '.red { color: red; }'
    ]
})
export class App {

  useRed = false;

  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    setTimeout(() => this.useRed = true, 1000);
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

And if you are using this `() =>` syntax, you dont have to save `this`!
The `this` context will only be lost if you are using the `function () {}` syntax..

Comment: Ah, you're right this does work. I was having the issue with setting animation states inside setTimeout() originally and tried to simplify it to just setting any property connected by data-binding in the setTimeout function. Unforunately I was not able to figure out why the setTimeout animation state changes didn't work, but I ended up hard-cording the animations and setting the delay property in the 'transition' of the animation. That way I can change the states when needed and not wrapped in a setTimeout function. Not the shortest solution but a decent workaround nonetheless.

Comment: In retrospect, I was putting the animation state changes in 'ngOnInit' when they should have been in 'ngOnViewChecked'...

Answer (score 0):

actually you can do this and it works in angular 9

```
this.isValueTrue = true;
window.setTimeout(()=>{
this.isValueTrue = false}, 3000)
```